# Sharing models between two Dockerizable Django projects and ForeignKey to a model

Tags: django, microservices

I want to create three Django projects. The projects sharing models between them on the same database like modular monolith structure. How Can I access a model from the other project for ForeignKey to a model.

I've been doing research and application on the subject, but I still haven't found how to set up a structure. I use InspectDB and ı can use shared model when development. How can I use this structure when ı use docker image for each project. Because when dockerize a project and run on the same machine, ı can not access any shared models.